# Unable to install apk to SD card

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm unable to install an application to virtual devices (API's 10 and 17) when I specify preferExternal in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Console output:

```
[2013-06-11 12:01:51 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2013-06-11 12:01:51 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-11 12:01:51 - MyApp] Performing com.mydomain.MyApp.activities.ChannelActivity activity launch
[2013-06-11 12:01:51 - MyApp] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'NexusS_API17' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-11 12:01:51 - MyApp] Uploading MyApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-11 12:01:55 - MyApp] Installing MyApp.apk...
[2013-06-11 12:01:59 - MyApp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR
[2013-06-11 12:01:59 - MyApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-06-11 12:01:59 - MyApp] Launch canceled!
```

LogCat output:

```
06-11 10:01:57.385: W/ActivityManager(302): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MyApp.apk
06-11 10:01:57.755: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32): Creating filesystem with parameters:
06-11 10:01:57.755: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Size: 2158592
06-11 10:01:57.755: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Block size: 4096
06-11 10:01:57.755: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Blocks per group: 32768
06-11 10:01:57.755: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Inodes per group: 144
06-11 10:01:57.755: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Inode size: 256
06-11 10:01:57.766: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Journal blocks: 0
06-11 10:01:57.775: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Label: 
06-11 10:01:57.775: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Blocks: 527
06-11 10:01:57.775: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Block groups: 1
06-11 10:01:57.785: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32):     Reserved block group size: 7
06-11 10:01:57.795: I//system/bin/make_ext4fs(32): Created filesystem with 11/144 inodes and 23/527 blocks
06-11 10:01:57.846: I/Vold(32): Filesystem (ext4) formatted OK
06-11 10:01:57.855: E/Vold(32): ASEC FAT mount failed (No such device)
06-11 10:01:57.926: E/PackageHelper(1091): Failed to create secure container smdl2tmp1
06-11 10:01:57.926: E/DefContainer(1091): Failed to create container smdl2tmp1
06-11 10:01:57.937: W/ActivityManager(302): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MyApp.apk
```

It looks like people have encountered a similar problem with [smdl2tmp1](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/04/19/fixing-the-couldnt-install-on-usb-storage-or-sd-card-problem-on-android/) in the past, but my AVD's don't have the smdl2tmp1.asec file. I've tried a number of things:

1. Recreating AVD's.
2. Unmounting /mnt/sdcard with umount in ADB (I get device busy).
3. Rebuilding development environment on another computer with a fresh install of ADT 22.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can get my app to install on the external sdcard? It runs fine when installing to internal storage.

Comment: I've just had this problem, turning off "Use host GPU" seemed to help me :)

Comment: Use host GPU wasn't checked, but I tried checking, retesting, and unchecking, and retesting. No change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your device to install the applications from now on in the external device, use the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#win-bundle) and check the `<sdk>/tools` and the `<sdk>/platform-tools` folders are in your path. Open the program and download the package `android-tools`.

[image]

Then connect your device, [enable USB debug mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9u7MD2H-wT8), check the firewall is not active and execute this command in a shell with "administrator priviledges":

> adb shell pm set-install-location 2

If it shows the error message:

> error: more than one device and emulator

Its because you have several devices (your real phone and other virtual devices, well known as AVDs). You can check what is your phone among them with this command.

> adb devices

I will show something like this:

[image]

In my case it were two active devices: one is an emulator(AVD), as it names indicates, and the other is my phone "99000200835402". If you have like in my case two devices with the same id, just kill the process "adb.exe" with the TaskManager, reconnect the phone and check again, it should be only device with an id without the "emulator-" prefix. So execute the following command:

adb -s "99000200835402" shell pm set-install-location 2

But with your phone id instead of **99000200835402**, it should look like this:

[image]

For more information visit the following links:

- [Cómo obligar Android a instalar apps en la tarjeta SD](http://articulos.softonic.com/como-obligar-android-a-instalar-apps-en-la-tarjeta-sd)
- [Move apps to external sd card and set installation location as sd card](http://www.technonutty.com/2012/06/android-move-apps-to-external-sd-card.html)
- [The Android Debug Bridge´s guide (ADB)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)